# Why would redirection work where piping fails?

Tags: windows, command-line

In theory, these two command-lines should be equivalent:

## 1

```
type tmp.txt | test.exe
```

## 2

```
test.exe < tmp.txt
```

I have a process involving #1 that, for many years, worked just fine; at some point within the last year, we started to compile the program with a newer version of Visual Studio, and it now fails due to malformed input (see below). But #2 succeeds (no exception and we see expected output). Why would #2 succeed where #1 fails?

I've been able to reduce test.exe to the program below. Our input file has exactly one tab per line and uniformly uses CR/LF line endings. So this program should never write to stderr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int __cdecl main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::istream* pIs = &std::cin;
    std::string line;

    int lines = 0;
    while (!(pIs->eof()))
    {
        if (!std::getline(*pIs, line))
        {
            break;
        }

        const char* pLine = line.c_str();
        int tabs = 0;
        while (pLine)
        {
            pLine = strchr(pLine, '\t');
            if (pLine)
            {
                // move past the tab
                pLine++;
                tabs++;
            }
        }

        if (tabs > 1)
        {
            std::cerr << "We lost a linebreak after " << lines << " good lines.\n";
            lines = -1;
        }

        lines++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run via #1, I get the following output, with the same numbers every time (in each case, it's because getline has returned two concatenated lines with no intervening linebreak); when run via #2, there's (correctly) no output:

```
We lost a linebreak after 8977 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 1468 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 20985 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 6982 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 1150 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 276 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 12076 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 2072 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 4576 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 401 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 6428 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 7228 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 931 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 1240 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 2432 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 553 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 6550 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 1591 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 55 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 2428 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 1475 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 3866 good lines.
We lost a linebreak after 3000 good lines.
```

Comment: I think this counts as minimal and complete now. To get to verifiable, I'd need to post the exact input file, but I don't see a way to attach files here.

Comment: you could provide a source code for a program that generates the input file e.g., [here's an attempt to demonstrate the same issue in Python](https://gist.github.com/zed/dd44ade13d313ceb8ba8e384ba1ff1ac)

Answer (score 4):

This turns out to be a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1902345/regression-fread-on-a-pipe-drops-some-newlines):

> The bug is in fact in the lower-level _read function, which the stdio
>   library functions (including both fread and fgets) use to read from a
>   file descriptor.
>
> The bug in _read is as follows: If…
>
> 1. you are reading from a text mode pipe,
> 2. you call _read to read N bytes,
> 3. _read successfully reads N bytes, and
> 4. the last byte read is a carriage return (CR) character,
>
> then the _read function will complete the read successfully but will
>   return N-1 instead of N. The CR or LF character at the end of the
>   result buffer is not counted in the return value.
>
> In the specific issue reported in this bug, fread calls _read to fill
>   the stream buffer. _read reports that it filled N-1 bytes of the
>   buffer and the final CR or LF character is lost.
>
> The bug is fundamentally timing-sensitive because whether _read can
>   successfully read N bytes from the pipe depends on how much data has
>   been written to the pipe. Changing the buffer size or changing when
>   the buffer is flushed may reduce the likelihood of the problem, but it
>   won’t necessarily work around the problem in 100% of cases.
>
> There are several possible workarounds:
>
> 1. use a binary pipe and do text mode CRLF => LF translation manually on the reader side. This is not particularly difficult to do
>      (scan the buffer for CRLF pairs; replace them with a single LF).
> 2. call ReadFile with _osfhnd(fh), bypassing the CRT’s I/O library on the reader side entirely (though this would also require manual
>      text mode translation, since the OS won’t do text mode translation for
>      you)
>
> We have fixed this bug for the next update to the Universal CRT. Note
>   that the Universal CRT is an operating system component and is
>   serviced independently from the Visual C++ libraries. The next update
>   to the Universal CRT will probably be around the same timeframe as the
>   Windows 10 Anniversary Update this summer.